# ¿Cómo ordenar y filtrar un archivo csv con pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Quiero obtener una matriz filtrada de un archivo scv con pandas, esta pensado para luego pasar los datos a tenserflow para hacer una AI que convierta a distintas unidades, y quería hacer un documento que se ordenara por tipos en primer nivel, luego por unidades, y luego los datos de entrada y salida, para dar un pequeño ejemplo:

```
Tipo| De Unidad| De Cantidad| A Unidad| A Cantidad|
Masa| Kilogramo|     xxxxxxx| Gramo   |    xxxxxxx|
Masa| Gramo    |     xxxxxxx| Kilogramo|    xxxxxxx|
Longitud| Metro|   xxxxxxx| Cenimetro|    xxxxxxx|
Longitud| Centimetro|xxxxxxx| metro|    xxxxxxx|
```

Espero que se entienda, y hasta ahí, importo el archivo y todo bien, pero luego quiero separara el archivo, ordenarlo por tipo y Unidad, para ahora tener una lista de todas las conversiones de kilogramos a gramos por ejemplo, pero que no contenga otro dato, y de está manera ir filtrando entre cada tipo de conversión

Aquí esta un enlace al [documento](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1latcLp8ZZ6_Cag0EVhxdCNFVk5Z1jupu/view?usp=sharing)

Y aquí un pequeño ejemplo de lo que he intentado:

```
Archivo = pd.read_csv("/content/datos.csv", sep=";")

x = Archivo.groupby(["Type", "From Unit", "To Unit", "From Quantity", "To Quantity"]).sum()
print(x)
```

De esta manera consigo que se agrupe medianamente bien, pero luego no logro filtrar esa lista, no se muy bien como conseguir eso, además siento que de esa manera es muy ineficiente.

Agregar "sort=False" a la variable x después de seleccionar las columnas logró que se ordene bien, pero aún así luego no puedo filtrar.

```
Archivo = pd.read_csv("/content/datos.csv", sep=";")

x = Archivo.groupby(["Type", "From Unit", "To Unit", "From Quantity", "To Quantity"], sort=False).sum()
print(x)
```

No estoy muy familiarizado con las terminologías de estas librerías así que si creen que debo mejorar el titulo comentarme por favor

Answer (score 0):

Lo que encontré fue una forma de filtrar, que no estoy seguro de que sea la mejor manera, así como estructurara el documento csv, ahora filtro de la siguiente manera:

```py
inputs = pd.read_csv("/content/entrenamiento.csv", sep=";")
#Para conseguir solo las longitudes
length = inputs[inputs.Types == "Length"]
#Para ir consiguiendo cada unidad. Ejmp: cm, m, km, etc...
Unidad_A = = length['Value_A']
```

Y ahora el documento lo estructure de una forma que había olvidado, pero es básicamente el equivalente de todas las unidades a la primer unidad, una imagen de ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El equivalente de 10cm a metros, kilómetros, millas, yardas y pies.
La verdad no estoy seguro de si es la mejor manera, pero lo escribo por si le puedo ser de ayuda a alguien en un futuro.

Comment: que yo sepa es la forma típica de hacer eso